# Industrial robot client : Are start and end sequence numbers not genenrated by default?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently working on implementing an custom Industrial Robot Server that talks with the default industrial robot client using the trajectory streamer interface. I got the communication between the robot and the robot client working but I'm now stuck on the detection of the start and end of an trajectory.  This page  http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/create_joint_position_streaming_interface_using_tcp_socket_libraries
states the following:

> SEQ_NUMBER – The sequence number is the number assigned by ROS to each of the points (i.e. this is always 0 or positive). A value of -1 indicates the end of a trajectory, a value of -2 indicates a stop (in both cases the controller stops, joint data is not valid for these special types)

And from:
https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_core/blob/indigo-devel/simple_message/include/simple_message/joint_traj_pt.h

I get that there are a few more "special" sequence numbers:

```
START_TRAJECTORY_DOWNLOAD  = -1, ///< Downloading drivers only: signal start of trajectory
START_TRAJECOTRY_STREAMING = -2, ///< deprecated, please use START_TRAJECTORY_STREAMING instead
START_TRAJECTORY_STREAMING = -2, ///< Streaming drivers only: signal start of trajectory
END_TRAJECTORY  = -3, ///< Downloading drivers only: signal end of trajectory
STOP_TRAJECTORY = -4  ///< Server should stop the current motion (if any) as soon as possible
```

However if I use Wireshark to look at the messages that are send to the robot I can see 18 messages been send but don't see the special sequence numbers -2 (START_TRAJECOTRY_STREAMING )or -3 (END_TRAJECTORY). However if I manually stop the trajectory the -4 (STOP_TRAJECTORY) is generated.

Could someone give me a few pointer as to where the special sequence numbers are generated, and why the are not generated in my case?

I'm using ros Jade on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with kernel 4.2.0.42 with all the latest packages installed from: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu repository.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245525/industrial-robot-client-:-are-start-and-end-sequence-numbers-not--genenrated-by-default-?/) by [mmoerdijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/27997/mmoerdijk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2016-10-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-12**:
Not an answer, but you might be interested in [Message Structures of the ROS-Industrial Simple Message Protocol](https://github.com/gavanderhoorn/rep-ros-i/blob/retrospective_simple_msg/rep-ixxxx.rst) (unfinished), which attempts to document the SM protocol in greater detail.

**Comment by [mmoerdijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/27997/mmoerdijk/) on 2016-10-12**:
Thanks, didn't know that document, could have saved me some time if I had know about it before :-). Was actually thinking about writing a similar document myself. Is there by any change more documentation about adding non standard messages? I'm now looking at the motoman rep to see how they did it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-12**:
No documentation yet, but we're working on a code generator similar to `gencpp` to generate Simple Message structs and msgs from ROS msg idls. That would make it a lot easier.

For now, just copying and adapting one of the existing msgs is probably easiest.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-12**:
See [motoman#93](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman/pull/93) for an example PR that shows how to add new msgs.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-12**:
And:

> Thanks, didn't know that document, could have saved me some time if I had know about it before

probably. That is one of the reasons we always ask / recommend ppl to talk to us first, as we can save you a lot of time and effort (and frustration).

**Comment by [mmoerdijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/27997/mmoerdijk/) on 2016-10-13**:
Yes would have been better, but I started out 3 weeks ago with ROS and did really know where to start asking :-). What would have been the right place to ask for a few pointers on implementing a "industrial robot server" it seems to me that it is a too general question for answers.ros.org.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-13**:
In this particular case a msg to the ROS-Industrial [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev) would have been a good start. We should probably make that more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you've run into something where the *download* and *streaming* drivers differ in their implementation. The `JointTrajectoryDownloader::send_to_robot(..)` method in the IRC does set the first and last points to these special sequence numbers ([here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_core/blob/98b076fca4bf6f74a2d8c3f197fb608afea68d9f/industrial_robot_client/src/joint_trajectory_downloader.cpp#L53-L54)), making it explicit for the server when the client starts and completes uploading a new trajectory.

The streaming driver unfortunately doesn't do this. Servers are expected to start executing a trajectory as soon as the first point (or a few, depending on server-side buffering requirements) has been received.

I wasn't involved when this part of the infrastructure was written, but I can speculate as to why this is: a streaming trajectory is potentially infinite. And as the driver should be *streaming*, it would be a violation of semantics to wait for a `END_TRAJECTORY` (note the comment on the enum value).

It would perhaps make sense for a streaming client to set the `START_TRAJECTORY_STREAMING`, to indicate to the server that a new motion is starting (and should fi replace the current one). But in practice most servers either assume that whatever they receive is part of a single trajectory and / or check the sequence numbers of consecutive traj pts and either error out if they are not contiguous, or assume a new trajectory has started.

This is certainly too implicit right now, and I've created an issue to track this: [ros-industrial/industrial_core#152](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_core/issues/152).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmoerdijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/27997/mmoerdijk/) on 2016-10-13**:
I don't know how I could miss that comment. Thank you for creating the issue and answering my question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-13**:
No problem. As I've said: we should probably make this all more explicit.

**Comment by [meimar12](https://answers.ros.org/users/29487/meimar12/) on 2017-05-13**:
Is this problem solved? Or it has been decided to leave it like that, just checking for the sequence number of the joint trajectory?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-14**:
No, this behaviour has not been changed. See also the ticket referenced in my answer.